Iterating over 2 input raster folders for raster calculator in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder
I'm currently on a project in ArcGIS Pro where I want to calculate the RVI of a RS time series collected by Sentinel-1. Unfortunately, I only have for each date one Tif-file for the VH and one Tif-file for the VV polarization. I have them stored in each a local folder "VH" and "VV". Now I use the ModelBuilder to batch process these images. In a sub-model, I iterate over the VV-rasters and clip them to the desired extent. Now I want to include them into the main model, where I iterate over the VH-images. Within this main model, I want to calculate the RVI by using the Raster calculator. Unfortunately, my sub-model VV output rasters can only be used as preconditions, but not as input data. I tried to apply the collect values function in the sub-model and the merge-function in the main model, but this does not work as I can only give the submodel's output as precondition.
Could you give me some advice?

It is incorrect to say "...can only give the submodel's output as precondition." A sub-model output can definitely be used as input to other tools. I suspect you are not defining the type of output the submodel is creating, so in the master model it can only use it as a precondition. Also sounds like you are passing around lists of rasters, you might be better off scripting this in python as that will be easier.

Thanks for your comment. I defined the output of the "collect values" tool as parameter but have no output table. Would the latter be necessary for further processing? And even possible to apply for raster iteration? If possible I would like to solve this within the model builder...
